# django-storages does not delete from S3

Tags: django

Using the [django-storages package](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) S3 when I delete an object it does not delete the image from my S3 file storage. There are no other objects I know of that are using the same image.

Would anyone know what is happening here is there a default I don't know about?

**models.py**

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=60,)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=300,)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2,)
        qr_url = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name="QR Code URL", help_text="Read only generated automatically.")
        qr_image = models.ImageField(
            upload_to="qr-codes",
            height_field="qr_image_height",
            width_field="qr_image_width",
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            editable=True,
            verbose_name="QR Code Image"
        )
        qr_image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
        qr_image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

        #FK
        category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory)

def product_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:
        instance._QRCODE = True
    else:
        if hasattr(instance, '_QRCODE'):
            instance._QRCODE = False
        else:
            instance._QRCODE = True

models.signals.pre_save.connect(product_pre_save, sender=Product)   



def product_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, '_already_saving'):
        del instance._already_saving
        return
    if instance._QRCODE:
        instance._QRCODE = False
    if instance.qr_image:
        instance.qr_image.delete()
        # Create url
    instance.qr_url = instance.create_QR_URL()
    qr = QRCode(4, QRErrorCorrectLevel.L)
    qr.addData(instance.qr_url)
    qr.make()
    image = qr.makeImage()


    #Save image to string buffer
    image_buffer = StringIO()
    image.save(image_buffer, format='JPEG')
    image_buffer.seek(0)

    #Here we use django file storage system to save the image.
    file_name = 'UrlQR_%s.jpg' % instance.id
    file_object = File(image_buffer, file_name)
    content_file = ContentFile(file_object.read())
    instance._already_saving = True
    instance.qr_image.save(file_name, content_file, save=True)


models.signals.post_save.connect(product_post_save, sender=Product)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your post_save action, you have:

```
...
if instance.qr_image:
        instance.qr_image.delete()
...
```

Which won't work, because you're trying to delete a field, not the instance, which is why Boto won't delete the file.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140779/how-to-delete-files-from-amazon-s3-bucket) for an example of how to delete an individual file with Boto.